# Drupal : customize status messages (of contact form)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-contact-form

I am setting up a website using drupal 6 and trying to be minimalistic. I use contact form, and it works pretty well. Once the message is sent, it is redirected to the front page of my site with a message "Your message has been sent.".(with a div messages status). How can one change it like,

1. customize the message content
2. instead of redirecting to the home page, display a node (another page)

thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more advanced forms and customisation like you mention above, you should try [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform). Webform has the ability to redirect a successful submission to another URL and have a custom status message as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the string for the message. To do that, you can either turn on the locale.module or get [string overrides module](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).
2. You can create a small custom module to redirect the user using the #redirect property of the Forms API. See [here](http://drupal.org/node/134000) for an example (and check the comments for potential issues).

Alternatively, consider using one of these modules:

[Node Destination](http://drupal.org/project/node_destination)

[Custom (Form) Destination](http://drupal.org/project/customdestination)

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

[Page manager redirect](http://drupal.org/project/page_manager_redirect)

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions... I think webform makes it way easier, as I could do all of it with just one module.